# how to make the notification not expand to the right bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to ask how to make the notification not expand to the right. I want the notification display to be responsive so that it can adjust itself.

Full code : https://pastebin.pl/view/cb415b64
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaQrN.png)

Code Notification :

```
<div class="float-end">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <!-- OPEN NOTIFICATION -->
                    <div class="btn-group dropstart">
                        <div class="section-title">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                                
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-3x" id="total" data-count="<?= $jlmh_log; ?>">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                                    fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bell-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path
                                    d="M8 16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2H6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2zm.995-14.901a1 1 0 1 0-1.99 0A5.002 5.002 0 0 0 3 6c0 1.098-.5 6-2 7h14c-1.5-1-2-5.902-2-7 0-2.42-1.72-4.44-4.005-4.901z" />
                                </svg></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-responsive ">
                                <div class="dropdown-header" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">Notification</div>
                                <?php 
                                foreach ($log as $value) { ?>                                   
                                <div class="dropdown-list-content dropdown-list-icons">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-unread">
                                        <div class="dropdown-item-desc dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                                        <i class="bi bi-bell"></i>
                                            <small><?= $value->id_log == 3 ? : NULL ; ?>Waka Sarana Prasarana
                                            <?= $value->log_desc; ?></small>
                                            <div class="time text-primary"><small><i class="bi bi-calendar-check-fill"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $value->log_time; ?></small></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <div class="float-end">

                                        <div class="dropdown-header" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"><a href="<?= site_url('notifikasi'); ?>">Lihat Semua</a></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="float-start">
                                        <div class="dropdown-header"><a href="<?= site_url('dashboard/del_notif')?>"><b>Hapus Notifikasi</b></a></div>
                                    </div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- CLOSE NOTIFICATION -->
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaQrN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-responsive ">` to `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">`. Also remove the `dropstart` class. See if it works?